# Plot multiple columns with different scales

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, multiple-axes

I have some data in the following format:

```
Section Env.    Ar.     Width   Length
    A   8.38    8.76    7      36
    B   11.84   13.51   11     57
    C   16.69   16.49   17     87
    D   11.04   11.62   9      44
    E   19.56   16.79   20     106
    F   17.93   21.34   19     98
```

I need to have a plot with `section` on X axis and `Env.` and `Ar.` on one Y axis and `Width` and `Length` on another Y axis, since it has a different scale. I know how to plot them in just one Y axis using `ggplot`, but I am stuck in how to do as I mentioned with two different Y axes. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/226759

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I have tried it before that could not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats about using this?

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- structure(list(Section = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", 
                 "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Env. = c(8.38, 11.84, 
                  16.69, 11.04, 19.56, 17.93), Ar. = c(8.76, 13.51, 16.49, 11.62, 
                  16.79, 21.34), Width = c(7L, 11L, 17L, 9L, 20L, 19L), Length = c(36L, 
                  57L, 87L, 44L, 106L, 98L)), .Names = c("Section", "Env.", "Ar.", 
                  "Width", "Length"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
d %>% 
  gather(key, value,-Section) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Section, value, colour=key, group= key)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.1) + geom_point(size=4)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Env_Ar",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Width_Length"))
```

[image]

You can also try using different facets with `"free_y"` scaling. This is IMO much more cleaner and elegant.

```
d %>% 
  gather(key, value,-Section) %>% 
  mutate(group=ifelse(key %in% c("Width","Length"), 2, 1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Section, value, colour=key, group= key)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.1) + geom_point(size=4)+
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

## Edit

Here an approach for a different scaling (10 times higher) of the right y-axis

```
d %>% 
  mutate(Width=Width*10,
         Length=Length*10) %>% 
  gather(key, value,-Section) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Section, value, colour=key, group= key)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.1) + geom_point(size=4)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Env_Ar",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Width_Length"))
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But, tin he first approach plots have the same Y-axis scales. What I am looking for is to have two different Y-aix scales in one plot.

Comment: This is clear. But then as also stated in the solution (above provided link) you have to scale the values by yourself. This can be done by multiplyinig, dividing or substracting a constant. I added an example in my answer.